# Why does the client have no reference to the invoker in the Command pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, uml

[Link to command pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html)

Why does the client have no reference to the invoker when it has references to receivers and concretecommands?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    StockTrade stock = new StockTrade();
    BuyStockOrder bsc = new BuyStockOrder (stock);
    SellStockOrder ssc = new SellStockOrder (stock);
    Agent agent = new Agent(); //<-- The invoker is right there yet it is not
                               // in the diagram?

    agent.placeOrder(bsc);
    agent.placeOrder(ssc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) article explains this as:

> The client instantiates the command
>   object and provides the information
>   required to call the method ***at a later
>   time. The invoker decides when the
>   method should be called.*** The receiver
>   is an instance of the class that
>   contains the method's code.

Comment: Dances around the root of the question, the point is that Client and Invoker can be decoupled, the "main" just happens create and call them both.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, the answer is this.

There is a reference in that diagram that can be traced from the Client to Invoker.  If you look you can see there is a dotted line from Client to ConcreteCommand called "instantiate" and then a line from ConcreteCommand to Command and then a line from Command to Invoker.

As I understand it -- this dotted line represents creating the objects for later use (as you can see from the code -- they are created in main.)